# function only works when clicked twice

Tags: javascript, html

i'm quite new when it comes to programming, so i do have some basic issues. one of them, that i can't really solve is the following:

i wrote a javascript code to change a div's content on a button click. it works fine, but only on the second click.

the buttons html:

```
 <li class="navli"><a class="navbutton" id="home" onclick="navClick(this.id)">Home</a></li>
```

the javascript:

```
var buttonId = "";
var contentText = "";

function navClick(clicked_id)
{
    buttonId = clicked_id;
    changeContent();
}

function changeContent(){
    fetch("./pages/"+buttonId+".txt")
    .then(function(response){
        return response.text()
        })
        .then(function(data){
            contentText = data;
        })
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = contentText;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an async mishap. Try it like this:

```js
var buttonId = "";
var contentText = "";

function navClick(clicked_id)
{
    buttonId = clicked_id;
    changeContent();
}

function changeContent(){
    fetch("./pages/"+buttonId+".txt")
    .then(function(response){
        return response.text()
    })
    .then(function(data){
        contentText = data;
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = contentText;
    })
}
```

The innerHMTML needs to be updated inside the `then`, otherwise it will probably run before the `fetch` completes. My best guess.